# Internet Explorer Add-Ins for SharePoint : Optimizing IE for SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, internet-explorer

I am in process preparing an OS image for re-image of 10k+ workstations. As part of the image, I am attempting to include an optimized copy of Internet Explorer 11 for use with SharePoint 2010. These are the following add-ins I would like to include. Am I missing, forgetting, or applying something that is incompatible?

- Internet Explorer Add-Ins

  - **SharePoint OpenDocuments Class**

    - "ActiveX control that enables users of Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 to create documents based on a specified template, or to edit documents using their associated applications."
    - When a page that contains a view of a document library opens, code in the file OWS.js determines whether Microsoft Office is installed and, if it is, instantiates the control."
    - This control is defined in the OWSSUPP.dll file, a dynamic-link library (DLL) that is installed in the %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office14\ directory on the client computer during Microsoft Office Setup.
    - **Verified**  http://bit.ly/1pbizgT   (MSDN)
  - **SharePoint OpenXMLDocuments**

    - "An ActiveX control that enables users of Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 to create XML documents or forms based on a specified template, or to edit XML documents or forms using their associated applications."
    - Unknown if Office is required for control instantiation. InfoPath is mentioned: One implementation of this control is defined in inlaunch.dll, a dynamic link-library (DLL) that is installed on the client computer during Microsoft InfoPath 2010 Setup.
    - http://bit.ly/1tx1jny   (MSDN)
  - **SharePoint ExportDatabaseLauncher**

    - An ActiveX control that enables a user to create or open a database that contains data from a list in Microsoft SharePoint Foundation
    - When a page that contains a view of a list opens, the _ExportToDatabase function is called, which is defined in the OWS.js file. This function creates the control on the page and exports the list.
    - This control is defined in OWSSUPP.dll, a dynamic-link library (DLL) that is installed in the %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office14\ directory on the client computer during Microsoft Office 2010 Setup.
    - **Verified** http://bit.ly/1p86cQ1 (MSDN)
  - **SharePoint SpreadsheetLauncher**

    - An ActiveX control that enables a user to import lists from spreadsheets, or to verify whether a compatible spreadsheet application is available for list export in Microsoft SharePoint Foundation
    - When a user clicks Export to Excel on the List Tools ribbon on a page that contains a list, the EnsureSSImporter function in INIT.js is called to verify that a version of the control is present on the client. Then the ExportList function in OWS.js is called to export the list.
    - **Verified** http://bit.ly/1kRj3oh   (MSDN)
  - **SharePoint Stssync Handler**

    - An ActiveX control that provides a method for returning the name of the application that is used to synchronize events lists and contacts lists in Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 with a messaging application such as Microsoft Outlook 2010.
    - This control is defined in the OWSSUPP.dll file, a dynamic-link library (DLL) that is installed in the Local_Drive:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE14 directory on the client computer during Microsoft Office Setup
    - **Verfied** http://bit.ly/1nc7Y5W  (MSDN)
  - **STSUploadCtl Class** or **UploadCtl**

    - An ActiveX control that enables multiple documents to be uploaded to a document library on a site in Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
    - This control is defined in the STSUPLD.dll file, a dynamic-link library (DLL) that is installed on the client computer in the %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office14\ directory during Microsoft Office 2010 Setup
    - When a user clicks Add document, the form for uploading documents, Upload.aspx, appears. If the user then clicks Upload Multiple Files, an  tag for the control is created on the page.
    - **Verified** http://bit.ly/1nc7Y5W (MSDN)
  - **Groove Site Client ActiveX**

    - Active X control added to IE add-ons on first use of 'Export to Excel'
    - More information needed
  - **NameCtrl Class**

    - Control is packaged in Office 20xx."when a page that contains a view of a document library opens, code in the file OWS.js determines whether Microsoft Office is installed and, if it is, instantiates the control"
    - **Verified** http://bit.ly/1jU3QYB (MSDN)
  - **Microsoft Office Visio 12 Diagram Launch Control** or **DiagramLauncher Control**

    - An ActiveX control that enables a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation user to create a Microsoft Visio 2010 diagram from a list if Visio 2010 is installed on the client computer.
    - This control is defined in DGRMLNCH.dll, a dynamic-link library (DLL) that is installed in the %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office14\ directory on the client computer when Visio 2010 is installed.
    - When a user clicks Create Visio Diagram on the List Tools ribbon on a page that contains a list, the ExportDiagram function in OWS.js is called. This function creates the control and uses the control to export a diagram.
    - **Verified** http://bit.ly/UqNQRM  (MSDN)

The majority (if not all) of these controls are installed during Office 20xx installation. This http://bit.ly/1nkmR5A MSDN article lists, in further detail, the above controls and others. I am continuing to investigate these other controls, which I have listed below:

- CopyCtl Control
- FFWinPlugin Plug-in
- ListNet Control
- OISClientLauncher Control
- Importing Contacts Using the Spreadsheet Launcher Control
- TaskLauncher Control

I will add that information to this question, if you have any details please let me know. I will be closing this question after I have determined if a full installation of Office is needed or if the libraries mentioned above can be deployed to a workstation in an minimalist office install profile.

Comment: What is your question? Great information! Shouldn't this be a wiki article instead of a question?

Answer (score 1):

Here are couples of:

- SharePoint Stssync Handler use to Connect to Outlook to synchronize
  lists
- STS Upld Upload Ctl Class ...Upload Multiple Docs
- Microsoft Office Visio 12 Diagram Launch Control... Create Visio Digram
  http://sharepoint4u.wordpress.com/2009/05/07/no-multiple-upload-no-connect-to-outlook/

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Office List  aka Office Data Connectivity Components aka STSLIST.DLL aka AccessDatabaseEngine.exe if your users need Datasheet View (2010 generation)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734